# Cheerio `this` object in TypeScript make "TS2683: 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation."

Tags: typescript, cheerio

I'm using Cheerio in a Typescript project to **scrape** a HTML page. But I don't understand how to solve the issue :

`TS2683: 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.`

Here is my code. Any idea ?

```js
import * as cheerioReq from 'cheerio-req';

async function crawl (options) {
    await cheerioReq({ url: options.url, headers: options.headers }, (err, $: CheerioStatic) => {
        if(err) console.log(err);

        $('.title').each((i, elem) => {
            console.log(i, elem, $(this).text().trim());
        })
    })

}

crawl(options);
```

Comment: The question is who do you expect `this` to be? If `this` should be passed in by `cheerioReq` try using a regular function not an arrow function

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this using a regular function.

1. First install **Cheerio types** in the terminal:
   `npm i @types/cheerio`
2. Next import Cheerio:  `import cheerio from 'cheerio';`
3. Finally change your code so that it looks as follows:

```
$('.title').each(function(this: CheerioElement, i, elem) {
   console.log(i, elem, $(this).text().trim());
})
```

** `this` and `elem` are the same in this context.

Comment: It's `cheerio.Element`, not `CheerioElement`

Comment: This is not working by today. `An arrow function cannot have a 'this' parameter.ts(2730)`